# Oracle Reports(Query and Report Triggers)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oraclereports, oracle-apps

**The query is:-**

```
/* Formatted on 5/18/2016 10:40:35 AM (QP5 v5.163.1008.3004) */
SELECT gcc.CODE_COMBINATION_ID,
       GCC.SEGMENT7 NATURAL_ACC,
       FFVT.DESCRIPTION NATURAL_ACC_DESC,
       GCC.SEGMENT10 BRANCH_CODE,
       GCC.SEGMENT4 MAIN_FUNC_CODE,
       GCC.SEGMENT3 BUS_FUNC_CODE,
       TRUNC (GJH.POSTED_DATE) VOUCHER_DATE,
       GJH.DOC_SEQUENCE_VALUE VOUCHER_NO,
       DECODE (GJH.JE_CATEGORY, '1', 'ETL', GJH.JE_CATEGORY) VOUCHER_TYPE,
       GJH.PERIOD_NAME,
       GJL.DESCRIPTION LINE_DESC,
       GJL.ACCOUNTED_DR DEBIT,
       GJL.ACCOUNTED_CR CREDIT,
       SUBSTR (ffv.COMPILED_VALUE_ATTRIBUTES, 5, 1) Account_Type,
       DECODE (
          Account_Type,
          'E', (SELECT NVL (
                          SUM (
                             NVL (gjl1.ACCOUNTED_DR, 0)
                             - NVL (gjl1.ACCOUNTED_CR, 0)),
                          0)
                  FROM gl_je_lines gjl1,
                       gl_je_headers gjh1,
                       gl_code_combinations gcc1
                 WHERE gjh1.JE_HEADER_ID = gjl1.JE_HEADER_ID
                       AND gjl1.CODE_COMBINATION_ID =
                              gcc1.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
                       AND gjh1.ledger_id = '2022'
                       AND gjh1.ACTUAL_FLAG = 'A'
                       AND gjl1.status = 'P'
                       AND gcc1.SEGMENT7 = gcc.SEGMENT7
                       AND TRUNC (GJH1.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) BETWEEN '01-JAN-'
                                                                       || TO_CHAR (
                                                                             TO_DATE (
                                                                                :P_DATE_FROM,
                                                                                ' YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS '),
                                                                             'YY')
                                                                   AND TO_CHAR (
                                                                          TO_DATE (
                                                                             :P_DATE_FROM,
                                                                             'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS ')
                                                                          - 1,
                                                                          'DD-MON-YY')                       &ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1
                     ),'R',( select   nvl(sum(nvl(gjl1.ACCOUNTED_DR,0) - nvl(gjl1.ACCOUNTED_CR,0)),0)
                   from         gl_je_lines gjl1,
                                gl_je_headers gjh1,
                                gl_code_combinations gcc1
                    where       gjh1.JE_HEADER_ID = gjl1.JE_HEADER_ID
                    and         gjl1.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = gcc1.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
                    and         gjh1.ledger_id = '2022'
                    and         gjh1.ACTUAL_FLAG = 'A'
                    and         gjl1.status = 'P'
                    and         gcc1.SEGMENT7 = gcc.SEGMENT7
                    and          trunc(GJH1.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE ) BETWEEN '01-JAN-'||to_char(to_date(:P_DATE_FROM,' YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS '),'YY')
                                                                     AND    to_char(to_date(:P_DATE_FROM,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS ')-1,'DD-MON-YY')
                            &ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1
                     ),( select sum(nvl(gjl1.ACCOUNTED_DR,0) - nvl(gjl1.ACCOUNTED_CR,0))
                    from        gl_je_lines gjl1,
                            gl_je_headers gjh1,
                            gl_code_combinations gcc1
                where       gjh1.JE_HEADER_ID = gjl1.JE_HEADER_ID
                and         gjl1.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = gcc1.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
                and         gjh1.ledger_id = '2022'
                and         gjh1.ACTUAL_FLAG = 'A'
                and         gjl1.status = 'P'
                and         gcc1.SEGMENT7 = gcc.SEGMENT7
                and          trunc(GJH1.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE ) < to_char(to_date(:P_DATE_FROM,' YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS '),'DD-MON-YY')
                         &ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1
                     )) Opening_balance




FROM    GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS    GCC,
        GL_JE_LINES                      GJL,
        GL_JE_HEADERS                GJH,
        FND_FLEX_VALUES            FFV,
        FND_FLEX_VALUES_TL      FFVT

WHERE   GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GJL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
AND     GJL.JE_HEADER_ID = GJH.JE_HEADER_ID
AND     FFV.FLEX_VALUE_ID = FFVT.FLEX_VALUE_ID
AND     GCC.SEGMENT7 = FFV.FLEX_VALUE
AND     FFV.FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = '1013540'
AND     GCC.SEGMENT7 <> '301010203004'
AND     GJH.ACTUAL_FLAG = 'A' --- JUZER MODIFIED -----
--and     gjh.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID is null
--and     gjh.JE_HEADER_ID not in ( select distinct nvl(a.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID,0)from gl_je_headers a where a.JE_HEADER_ID <> gjh.JE_HEADER_ID )
AND     GJL.STATUS = 'P'
--and         trunc(gjh.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) between :p_date_from and :p_date_to
AND     GCC.SEGMENT7 between :P_NAT_ACCT1 and :P_NAT_ACCT2
and       trunc(GJH.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE ) BETWEEN to_char(to_date(:P_DATE_FROM,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS '),'DD-MON-YY')
                                             AND     to_char(to_date(:P_DATE_TO,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS '),'DD-MON-YY')
&ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE

ORDER BY GCC.SEGMENT7,GJH.POSTED_DATE
```

**and in its report trigger it have this after parameter form**

/* Formatted on 5/18/2016 10:37:19 AM (QP5 v5.163.1008.3004) */

```
FUNCTION AfterPForm
   RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
   LV_DATE_FROM   VARCHAR2 (100);
   LV_DATE_TO     VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   IF :P_BRANCH_CODE IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE :=
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE || ' AND GCC.SEGMENT10 = :P_BRANCH_CODE ';
   END IF;


   /*        IF :P_DATE_FROM IS NOT NULL AND :P_DATE_TO IS NOT NULL THEN
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE  := :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE   || ' AND TRUNC(GJH.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:P_DATE_FROM,''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),''DD-MON-YYYY'') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:P_DATE_TO,''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),''DD-MON-YYYY'') ';
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1 := :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1 || ' and trunc(gjh1.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) < to_char(to_date(:P_DATE_FROM,''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),''DD-MON-YYYY'') ';
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3 := :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3 || ' and trunc(gjh3.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) < to_char(to_date(:P_DATE_FROM,''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),''DD-MON-YYYY'') ';
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE4  := :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE4   || ' AND TRUNC(GJH4.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:P_DATE_FROM,''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),''DD-MON-YYYY'') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:P_DATE_TO,''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),''DD-MON-YYYY'') ';
       END IF;
       */



   IF :P_SOURCE IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      IF :P_SOURCE = 'ETL'
      THEN
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE
            || ' and gjh.JE_SOURCE = ''1'' and gjh.JE_CATEGORY = ''1'' and gjh.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID is null and gjh.JE_HEADER_ID not in ( select distinct nvl(a.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID,0)from gl_je_headers a where a.JE_HEADER_ID <> gjh.JE_HEADER_ID )';
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1 :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1
            || ' and gjh1.JE_SOURCE = ''1'' and gjh1.JE_CATEGORY = ''1''and gjh1.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID is null and gjh1.JE_HEADER_ID not in ( select distinct nvl(a.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID,0)from gl_je_headers a where a.JE_HEADER_ID <> gjh1.JE_HEADER_ID ) ';
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3 :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3
            || ' and gjh3.JE_SOURCE = ''1'' and gjh3.JE_CATEGORY = ''1''and gjh3.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID is null and gjh3.JE_HEADER_ID not in ( select distinct nvl(a.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID,0)from gl_je_headers a where a.JE_HEADER_ID <> gjh3.JE_HEADER_ID ) ';
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE4 :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE4
            || ' and gjh4.JE_SOURCE = ''1'' and gjh4.JE_CATEGORY = ''1''and gjh4.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID is null and gjh4.JE_HEADER_ID not in ( select distinct nvl(a.REVERSED_JE_HEADER_ID,0)from gl_je_headers a where a.JE_HEADER_ID <> gjh4.JE_HEADER_ID ) ';
      ELSIF :P_SOURCE = 'OFSA'
      THEN
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE
            || ' and  gjh.JE_SOURCE <> ''1'' and gjh.JE_CATEGORY <> ''1''';
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1 :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1
            || ' and  gjh1.JE_SOURCE <> ''1'' and gjh1.JE_CATEGORY <> ''1''';
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3 :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3
            || ' and  gjh3.JE_SOURCE <> ''1'' and gjh3.JE_CATEGORY <> ''1''';
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3 :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3
            || ' and  gjh3.JE_SOURCE <> ''1'' and gjh3.JE_CATEGORY <> ''1''';
         :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE4 :=
            :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE4
            || ' and  gjh4.JE_SOURCE <> ''1'' and gjh4.JE_CATEGORY <> ''1''';
      END IF;
   END IF;


   /*
   IF :P_PERIOD_FROM IS NOT NULL AND :P_PERIOD_TO IS NOT NULL THEN

       SELECT  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(GP.START_DATE),'DD-MON-YYYY')
       INTO    LV_DATE_FROM
       FROM    GL_PERIODS GP
       WHERE   GP.PERIOD_NAME = :P_PERIOD_FROM
       AND         PERIOD_SET_NAME = 'NIB_Calendar';

       SELECT  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(GP.END_DATE),'DD-MON-YYYY')
       INTO    LV_DATE_TO
       FROM    GL_PERIODS GP
       WHERE   GP.PERIOD_NAME = :P_PERIOD_TO
       AND         PERIOD_SET_NAME = 'NIB_Calendar';

       :P_DATE_FROM := LV_DATE_FROM;
       :P_DATE_TO   := LV_DATE_TO;

       :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE   :=  :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE  || ' and trunc(gjh.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) between :p_date_from and :p_date_to';
       :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1  :=  :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE1 || ' and trunc(GJH1.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE ) <= (SELECT A.START_DATE-1 FROM GL_PERIODS A WHERE A.PERIOD_NAME = GJH.PERIOD_NAME ) ';
       :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3  :=  :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE3 || ' and trunc(GJH3.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE ) <= (SELECT A.START_DATE-1 FROM GL_PERIODS A WHERE A.PERIOD_NAME = :P_PERIOD_FROM) ';
       :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE4  :=  :ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE4 || ' and trunc(gjh4.DEFAULT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) between :p_date_from and :p_date_to';

   END IF;
   */



   RETURN (TRUE);
END;
```

I want to run the query on top on toad

It asks for add_where_clause parameter can anyone tell me what value to put someone told me that report trigger add_where_clause would come.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

write `Set define off;` top of the your function script and press f5 button.

Answer (score 0):

You have this at the end of your query:

> &ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE ORDER BY GCC.SEGMENT7,GJH.POSTED_DATE

I guess you should delete &ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE and then execute query or replace &ADD_WHERE_CLAUSE with your WHERE clause